# Find position of a substring in a string(not indexOf)

Tags: java, string, position, substring

ex

```
String str = "abc def ghi";
```

Is there any method like `str.find("abc")` will return me 1
and `str.find("def")` will return me 2?

java language..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
int getIndex(String str, String substring)
{
  return Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s+")).indexOf(substring)+1;
}
```

**Disclaimer:** This isn't at all efficient. It splits the whole string from scratch every time the function is called.

**Test code:**

```
String str = "abc def ghi";
System.out.println(getIndex(str, "abc"));
System.out.println(getIndex(str, "def"));
```

**Prints:**

```
1
2
```

**Explanation:**

`str.split("\\s+")` splits the string by white-space and puts each part into a position in an array.

`Arrays.asList` returns an `ArrayList` for the array.

`indexOf(substring)` finds the position of the string in the `ArrayList`.

`+1` since Java uses 0-indexing and you want 1-indexing.

Comment: +1 for the one liner but maybe expanding your code will make it more readable for the OP...

Comment: @Marc It seems like such a waste to make it longer. I'm hoping the added explanation will make it readable enough.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not requesting for index of a substring but instead which word position the substring belong to, there is no such built-in method available. But you can split the input string by space character and read each item in the list returned by the split method and check at which list item position your substring belongs to.

Let me know, if you need code for this.

Comment: -1 Good explanation, but you always need to show code in your answer, otherwise this is just a long comment

Comment: Thanks RGraham for your valuable feedback. I will ensure this going forward.

Comment: @RGraham Sure code usually helps to explain better. But I disagree that one should *always need to* add code in the answers. A guide for OP is a good answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a native function for this. But you could write your own.

It seems like you want to split the string based on the white space character.

```
String[] parts = string.split(" ");
```

Loop through the array created.  And return the index + 1 (As java has zero based indexes)

```
for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
{
  if(parts[i].equals(parameter))
  {
     return i + 1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to find multiple positions of the same string try this code.

```
//Returns an array of integers with each string position
private int[] getStringPositions(String string, String subString){
        String[] splitString = string.split(subString); //Split the string

        int totalLen = 0; //Total length of the string, added in the loop

        int[] indexValues = new int[splitString.length - 1]; //Instances of subString in string

        //Loop through the splitString array to get each position
        for (int i = 0; i < splitString.length - 1; i++){

            if (i == 0) {
                //Only add the first splitString length because subString is cut here.
                totalLen = totalLen + splitString[i].length();
            }
            else{
                //Add totalLen & splitString len and subStringLen
                totalLen = totalLen + splitString[i].length() + subString.length();
            }

            indexValues[i] = totalLen; //Set indexValue at current i
        }

        return indexValues;
    }
```

So for example:

```
String string = "s an s an s an s"; //Length = 15
String subString = "an";
```

Answer would return indexValues = (2, 7, 12).